# I can’t export entries correctly from Visual Form Builder

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to export entries in .csv format but i recive this message [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiNaw.png)

When i put original jquery with theme, this error is gone but problem with entries stays same.

> No entries to pull field names from.

I checked in database and all data is there. Also I checked class-export.php file and code looks good. When I export the file, I have data which is not useful such as IP address, data submitted etc.

Comment: please share a plugin url

Comment: exporting entires or json?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/visual-form-builder/  Exporting, not a json. I have wrong data in .csv file and tables colums which i should select in dashboard/plugin interface doesnt show up.

Comment: Fields box cant reload with a list of available fields in my case.

Comment: You need to check a website is there any js error.

Comment: I checked everything, i updated jquery. Only thing that i didnt do it is turninf off all plugins to see if there is some conflict there. The website is already online, so i wanted to eliminate all other possibilites before i do that.

Comment: are you technical person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step to Entries Export**

- The Entries export option will create either a .csv, .txt, or .xls
  file and cannot be used with the Import. This is most useful when you
  want tabulated data for use in a spreadsheet application.
- Use the Select a Form box below the radio option. If any entries are
  available for that form, the Fields box will reload with a list of
  available fields. You can then use the Date Range boxes to select a
  Start and End date to narrow the number of entries down.  Leave the
  Date Range boxes blank if you wish to export all entries for that
  form.
- Use the Select a Form box below the radio option. If any entries are
  available for that form, the Fields box will reload with a list of
  available fields.
- Choose your desired Format (csv, txt, or xls)
- The Start and End date boxes will narrow the number of entries down
  to your selected Date Range. Leave these boxes blank if you wish to
  export all entries for that form.
- Select the Fields you wish to be displayed in your spreadsheet.
- Click the Download Export File button so the export file can be
  created and saved to your computer.